# PostgreSQL - CREATE TABLE - Apply constraints like PRIMARY KEY in attributes that are inside composite types

Tags: postgresql, create-table

I want to implement an object-relational database, using `PostgreSQL`. I do not want to use `ORACLE`.
Can I create a composite type, and then use it in a table, adding a restriction for example of a primary key in one of its attributes?
Below I leave an example:

```
CREATE TYPE teamObj AS (
    idnumeric,
    name character varying,
    city character varying,
    estadiumName character varying,
    jugadores playerObj[]
);

CREATE TABLE teamTable (
    equipo equipoobj,
    PRIMARY KEY (equipo.id)
);
```

The line **PRIMARY KEY (equipo.id)** gives an error, and I've read a lot of documentation of this topic, and I don't find the solution, maybe PostgreSQL has not implemented yet, or will never implement it, or I don't understand how runs PostgreSQL...

Does somebody have a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I feel you only need a table ```team```.. PostgreSQL will automatically provide you the type ```team``` with the same datatypes and attributenames as a row of the table.

Comment: I don't think you can; I've tried every variation, including those claimed to work by other SO questions, and didn't find anything to work. I'd concur with Islingre though; using a type in the way you propose to here will only make everything more hard work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that, and I recommend that you do **not** create tables like that.

Your table definition should look pretty much like your type definition does. There is no need for an intermediate type definition.

Reasons:

- that will not make your schema more readable
- that violates the first normal form for relational databases
- that does not match an object oriented design any better than the simple table definition

As a comfort, PostgreSQL will implicitly define a composite type of the same name whenever you define a table, so you can do things like

```
CAST(ROW(12, 'Raiders', 'Wolfschoaßing', 'Dorfwiesn', NULL) AS team)
```

or

```
CREATE FUNCTION getteam(id) RETURNS team
```

Comment: I have given up trying. I've been using Oracle for years, and I think PostgreSQL doesn't implement it the same way. So it is I who must change. I will do it as you tell me. Thank you.

Comment: You wouldn't define a table like that in Oracle either. It is just not a good database design to use composite types unnecessarily.